# Angular.json - set default configuration for test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'd like to know if there is a way to set default configuration for `ng test` in `angular.json` file.

I have this tree:

```
...
"projects": {
  "myProject": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          ...
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            ...
          },
          "development": {
            ...
          }
        }
      },
      "serve": {
        ...
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "myProject:build:development"
        },
      },
      "test": {
        "options": {
          "browserTarget": "myProject:build:development",
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

So I have the `serve` default set to `build:development` by setting `options.browserTarget` and thus when I run `ng serve`, the CLI runs the `development` configuration.

Now, what should I do to run `build:development` when I run `ng test` without any `--configuration` setting, when there is obviously no `options.browserTarget` setting? This configuration throws this error for `ng test`:

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(browserTarget).
```

And what is the proper solution to set default configuration for `ng build`?

Answer (score 2):

Under your test section you can add the following tag **defaultConfiguration** this should specify the default to be used. This can also be added to the **serve** tag

```
"test": {
    "builder": ..,
    "options": {
       ...
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
}
```

Comment: Which version of Angular CLI are we talking about? In our project we use V10 and this suggested way was probably the first one I tried. And for me it does not work.

Comment: We are using CLI v13. In your question you asked. And what is the proper solution to set default configuration for ng build, you can use the same above defaultConfiguration but in the build section of the angular.json file.